# How to handle StoreEvent in editable grid ?? GXT

Tags: eclipse, grid, gxt

I have created an editable grid with only 3 columns out of 5 as editable.
i need to retrieve the number entered in these editable cells and add them to display in the other cells of same grid. ive added a storeListener to the ListStore that contains preloaded grid data. and overriden storeUpdate(StoreEvent se) method. but im not getting how to retrieve the updated data using this update event.... pls help me guys.......
the code is like this

```
package org.openxdata.analyzer.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ComponentEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Events;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.GridEvent; 
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Listener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnConfig;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnModel;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Style.HorizontalAlignment;  
import java.util.List;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.StoreEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.StoreListener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.CellEditor;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.EditorGrid;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FormData;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ButtonEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.SelectionListener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Viewport;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.NumberField;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.ModelData;


public class Grid1 extends Viewport {

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        setStyleAttribute("margin", "10px");



        final Window w = new Window();
        w.setHeading("grids");
        w.setSize(600,250);
        w.setModal(true);
        //w.setLayout(new RowLayout(Orientation.VERTICAL)); 
        w.setLayout(new FitLayout());
        w.setResizable(false);

        FormData formData = new FormData("98%");


        List<ColumnConfig> col = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
        ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("disease");
        column.setWidth(150);
        TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>();    
        text.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text.setAutoValidate(true);    
        //column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text));  
        col.add(column);


        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("exposure");
        column.setWidth(120);
        TextField<String> text1 = new TextField<String>();    
        text1.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text1.setAutoValidate(true);    
        //column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text1));  
        col.add(column);

        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("plus");
        column.setHeader("Exposure");
        column.setWidth(80);
    final NumberField text2 = new NumberField();    
        text2.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text2.setAutoValidate(true);    
        column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text2));  
        col.add(column);

        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("minus");
        column.setHeader("Exposure");
        column.setWidth(80);
        final NumberField text3 = new NumberField();   
        text3.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text3.setAutoValidate(true);    
        column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text3));  
        col.add(column);

        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("total");
        column.setHeader("Totals");
        column.setWidth(80);
        final NumberField text4 = new NumberField();      
        text4.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text4.setAutoValidate(true);    
        column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text4));  
        column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        col.add(column);
        //ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(col);

        ListStore<Grid2> employeeList = new ListStore<Grid2>();    
        employeeList.add(cool.getgrid());




        employeeList.addStoreListener(new StoreListener<Grid2>() {


        @Override
        public void storeUpdate(StoreEvent<Grid2> se) {




            //doStoreUpdate(se);


        }
        });

        ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(col);  


        final EditorGrid<Grid2> grid = new EditorGrid<Grid2>(employeeList, cm);  
        //grid.setStyleAttribute("borderTop", "none");  
        //grid.setAutoExpandColumn("name");  
        grid.setBorders(true);  
        grid.setStripeRows(true);  

        /*
        grid.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
             public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent ce) {

            }
        });

            */
        w.add(grid);
        w.show();
    }
}


class Grid2 extends BaseModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Grid2(){
    }
    public Grid2  ( String  dis, String exp, Integer x,Integer y) {
        set("disease", dis);
        set("exposure", exp);
        set("plus", x);
        set("minus", y);
    }

    public Grid2 (String  dis, String exp, Integer x,
            Integer y, Double v) {
        // this(dis, exp, x,y,v);
        set("disease", dis);
        set("exposure", exp);
        set("plus", x);
        set("minus", y);
        set("total", v);
    }
    public Grid2(String a,String b,String c,String d,String t){
        set("disease",a);
        set("exposure",b);
        set("plus",c);
        set("minus",d);
        set("total",t);
    }
    public  Integer getplus() {
        return (Integer)get("plus");
    }
    public Integer getminus() {
        return (Integer)get("minus");
    }


    public class TestData {  

        public  List<Grid2> getData()  
        {  
            List<Grid2> lt= new ArrayList<Grid2>();  



            lt.add(new Grid2("Christina Blake","Information Technology",1,2,1.23));  
            lt.add(new Grid2("Heriberto Rush","Information Technology",3,4,1.334));  

            return lt;  
        }  
    }  

}

class cool {  

    public static  List<Grid2> getgrid()  
    {  
        List<Grid2> data = new ArrayList<Grid2>();  

        //data.add(new Grid(" "," ","Exposure"," ","Totals"));  
        data.add(new Grid2(" "," ","(+)","(-)"," "));  
        data.add(new Grid2("'Disease'","(+)",0,0,0.00));  
        data.add(new Grid2(" ","(-)",0,0,0.00));  
        data.add(new Grid2("Totals"," ",0,0,0.00));  


        return data;  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just make some of changes in you Code just check it out This Code This will Help You.

```
package org.openxdata.analyzer.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Style.HorizontalAlignment;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.BaseEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Events;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.GridEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Listener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.StoreEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.StoreListener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Viewport;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.NumberField;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.CellEditor;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnConfig;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnModel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.EditorGrid;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FormData;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;


public class Grid1 extends Viewport {

@Override
protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
    super.onRender(parent, index);
    setStyleAttribute("margin", "10px");



    final Window w = new Window();
    w.setHeading("grids");
    w.setSize(600,250);
    w.setModal(true);
    //w.setLayout(new RowLayout(Orientation.VERTICAL)); 
    w.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    w.setResizable(false);

    FormData formData = new FormData("98%");


    List<ColumnConfig> col = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
    ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("disease");
    column.setWidth(150);
    TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>();    
    text.setAllowBlank(false);    
    text.setAutoValidate(true);    
    //column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text));  
    col.add(column);


    column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("exposure");
    column.setWidth(120);
    TextField<String> text1 = new TextField<String>();    
    text1.setAllowBlank(false);    
    text1.setAutoValidate(true);    
    //column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text1));  
    col.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("plus");
    column.setHeader("Exposure");
    column.setWidth(80);
final NumberField text2 = new NumberField();    
    text2.setAllowBlank(false);    
    text2.setAutoValidate(true);    
    column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text2));  
    col.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("minus");
    column.setHeader("Exposure");
    column.setWidth(80);
    final NumberField text3 = new NumberField();   
    text3.setAllowBlank(false);    
    text3.setAutoValidate(true);    
    column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text3));  
    col.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("total");
    column.setHeader("Totals");
    column.setWidth(80);
    final NumberField text4 = new NumberField();      
    text4.setAllowBlank(false);    
    text4.setAutoValidate(true);    
    column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text4));  
    column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    col.add(column);
    //ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(col);

    ListStore<Grid2> employeeList = new ListStore<Grid2>();    
    employeeList.add(Cool.getgrid());




    employeeList.addStoreListener(new StoreListener<Grid2>() {


    @Override
    public void storeUpdate(StoreEvent<Grid2> se) {




        //doStoreUpdate(se);


    }
    });

    ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(col);  


    final EditorGrid<Grid2> grid = new EditorGrid<Grid2>(employeeList, cm);  
    //grid.setStyleAttribute("borderTop", "none");  
    //grid.setAutoExpandColumn("name");  
    grid.setBorders(true);  
    grid.setStripeRows(true);  

    /*
    grid.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
         public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent ce) {

        }
    });

        */
    w.add(grid);
    w.show();

    grid.addListener(Events.AfterEdit, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
            GridEvent ge = (GridEvent) be;

                Double plusTotal = 0.0;
                Double minusTotal = 0.0;
                for(int i=1 ; i < grid.getStore().getCount();i++ ){
                    if(grid.getStore().getAt(i).get("disease").toString().equals("Totals")){
                        grid.getStore().getAt(i).set("plus",plusTotal);
                        grid.getStore().getAt(i).set("minus",minusTotal);
                        grid.getStore().getAt(i).calculateTotal();
                        grid.getStore().commitChanges();
                    }else{
                        plusTotal = plusTotal + (grid.getStore().getAt(i).getplus());
                        minusTotal = minusTotal + (grid.getStore().getAt(i).getminus());
                    }
                }

                grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().calculateTotal();
                grid.getStore().commitChanges();
        }
    });
}
}


package org.openxdata.analyzer.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel;

class Grid2 extends BaseModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Grid2(){
    }
    public Grid2  ( String  dis, String exp, Integer x,Integer y) {
        set("disease", dis);
        set("exposure", exp);
        set("plus", x);
        set("minus", y);
    }

    public Grid2 (String  dis, String exp, Integer x,
            Integer y, Double v) {
        // this(dis, exp, x,y,v);
        set("disease", dis);
        set("exposure", exp);
        set("plus", x);
        set("minus", y);
        set("total", v);
    }
    public Grid2(String a,String b,String c,String d,String t){
        set("disease",a);
        set("exposure",b);
        set("plus",c);
        set("minus",d);
        set("total",t);
    }
    public  Double getplus() {
        return Double.valueOf(get("plus").toString());
    }
    public Double getminus() {
        return Double.valueOf(get("minus").toString());
    }

    public void calculateTotal(){
        set("total",(getplus() - getminus()));
    }

    public class TestData {  

        public  List<Grid2> getData()  
        {  
            List<Grid2> lt= new ArrayList<Grid2>();  



            lt.add(new Grid2("Christina Blake","Information Technology",1,2,1.23));  
            lt.add(new Grid2("Heriberto Rush","Information Technology",3,4,1.334));  

            return lt;  
        }  
    }  

}


package org.openxdata.analyzer.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cool {

    public static  List<Grid2> getgrid()  
    {  
        List<Grid2> data = new ArrayList<Grid2>();  

        //data.add(new Grid(" "," ","Exposure"," ","Totals"));  
        data.add(new Grid2(" "," ","(+)","(-)"," "));  
        data.add(new Grid2("'Disease'","(+)",0,0,0.00));  
        data.add(new Grid2(" ","(-)",0,0,0.00));  
        data.add(new Grid2("Totals"," ",0,0,0.00));  


        return data;  
    }
}
```